# Jmeter custom functions

Tags: java, jmeter

I need to create a custom function in Jmeter, and because of performance issues I can't use beanshell.

I wrote a java class following http://gabenell.blogspot.com/2010/01/custom-functions-for-jmeter.html and http://code4reference.com/2013/06/jmeter-custom-function-implementation/, but when I compile it I can't seem to get Jmeter to recognize it.

My class:

```
package custom.functions;

import org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable;
import org.apache.jmeter.functions.AbstractFunction;
import org.apache.jmeter.functions.InvalidVariableException;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.Sampler;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Username extends AbstractFunction{
    private static final List<String> desc = new LinkedList<String>();
    private static final String KEY = "__Username";
    private int number = 0;

    static {
        desc.add("Pass a random value to get a valid username for the system.");
    }

    public Username() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized String execute(SampleResult previousResult, Sampler currentSampler)
            throws InvalidVariableException {
        try {
            return getValue(number);
        } catch(Exception e){
            throw new InvalidVariableException(e);
        }
    }

    public String getValue(int number){
        return "John-Smith";
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setParameters(Collection<CompoundVariable> parameters) throws InvalidVariableException {
        checkParameterCount(parameters, 1, 1);
        Object[] values = parameters.toArray();
        number = Integer.parseInt(((CompoundVariable) values[0]).execute().trim());
    }

    @Override
    public String getReferenceKey() {
        return KEY;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getArgumentDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
}
```

When I run `jar tf custom-functions.jar` (to verify that the class file is in the jar):

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
custom/
custom/functions/
custom/functions/Username.class
```

I placed the jar in my jmeter lib/ext directory and tried running jmeter by itself and with `-Jsearch_paths=../lib/ext/custom-functions.jar`, but either way when I open the function helper tool it's not listed, and a simple test plan to verify the function sends instead `%24%7B__Username%281%29%7D`.

Am I not putting the file in the right place? Is it named incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had compiled my class using Java 8 instead of Java 7, which was the runtime I was using for jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

You can put groovy-all.jar on the classpath of Jmeter, and then you will be able to run external .groovy scripts or you can add a JSR223-Groovy Sampler.